# Node.js request to xml document not receiving properly encoded format?

Tags: xml, node.js, parsing

I am not entirely sure why, but I am receiving data that looks like `n�F����S�` from a call to an rss feed that is formatted in xml.

```
    exports.search = function(req, res) {
        request.get('https://secret.co/usearch/'+req.params.id+'/?rss=1', function (error, response, body) {
          console.log(body);
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            parseString(body, function (err, result) {
              res.json(result);
            });
          }
        });
    };
```

Just on a particular url, I am wondering how I can solve this and get proper xml?

Comment: Could you add the URL that causes your trouble to the question?

Comment: https:  //kat.cr/usearch/scarface/?rss=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL in question delivers content gzip encoded. Adding the option `gzip : true` to the request call will fix the problem:

```
exports.search = function(req, res) {
    request({ method : 'GET', url: 'https://kat.cr/usearch/scarface/?rss=1', gzip: true }, function(error, response, body) {
      console.log(body);
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        parseString(body, function (err, result) {
          res.json(result);
        });
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: What does one do to see that? Inside the chrome developer tools?

Comment: In chrome dev tools under network tab you'll find a Content-Encoding column that says "gzip" for gzipped responses. I recommend using curl for debugging these kinds of low level HTTP problems cause Chrome does a lot of magic to HTTP responses.